# Remove stuff, retrieve numbers, retrieve text with spaces in place of dots, remove the rest

Tags: regex, macos

This is my first question, so I hope I didn't mess too much with the title and the formatting.

I have a bunch of file a client of mine sent me in this form:

> Name.Of.Chapter.021x212.The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter.DOC.NAME-Some.stuff.Here.ext

What I need is a regex to output just:

> 212 The Actual Title Of the Chapter

I'm not gonna use it with any script language in particular; it's a batch renaming of **files** through an app supporting regex (which already "preserves" the extension).

So far, all I was able to do was this:

```
/.*x(\d+)\.(.*?)\.[A-Z]{3}.*/ -->REPLACE: $1 $2
```

*(Capture everything before a number preceded by an "x", group numbers after the "x", group everything following until a 3 digit Uppercase word is met, then capture everything that follows)*
which gives me back:

> 212 The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter

Having seen the result I thought that something like:

```
/.*x(\d+)\.([^.]*?)\.[A-Z]{3}.*/ -->REPLACE: $1 $2
```

*(Changed second group to "Capture everything **which is not a dot**...")*  would have worked as expected.
Instead, the whole regex fails to match completely.

What am I missing?

TIA

cià
ale

Answer (score 2):

`.*x(\d+)\.` matches `Name.Of.Chapter.021x212.`

`\.[A-Z]{3}.*` matches `.DOC.NAME-Some.stuff.Here.ext`

But `([^.]*?)` does not match `The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter` because this regex does not allow for any periods at all.

Comment: But if I only run "([^.]*?)\." on "The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter" (or the whole original string), it matches.
How come it doesn't in the full regex above?

And, btw... any hint on what I should do to get the result I need?
Tnx.

Comment: You have a regex which should allow you to rename the file `212 The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter`. Why not simply do a second pass with your renamer app which removes periods?

Comment: As I told **ghostdog**, at this point it's more a matter of *learning* regex than having the job done. I could use the shell, AppleScript or even the renamer app alone without any regex (and a few steps more), but what I really want to know now is if and how can it be done with regex in a single step.   
Sure enough, if it turns out it's not possible, the two-pass solution would be my best choice ;)   
**TNX!**

Answer (score 1):

since you are on Mac, you could use the shell

```
$ s="Name.Of.Chapter.021x212.The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter.DOC.NAME-Some.stuff.Here.ext"

$ echo ${s#*x}
212.The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter.DOC.NAME-Some.stuff.Here.ext

$ t=${s#*x}

$ echo ${t%.[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*}
212.The.Actual.Title.Of.the.Chapter
```

Or if you prefer sed, eg

```
echo $filename | sed 's|.[^x]*x||;s/\.[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*//'
```

For processing multiple files

```
for file in *.ext
do
  newfile=${file#*x}
  newfile=${newfile%.[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*}
  # or 
  # newfile=$(echo $file | sed 's|.[^x]*x||;s/\.[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z].*//')
  mv "$file" "$newfile"
done
```

Comment: Yes, you're totally right, **ghostdog**. But I've been stuck with finding a regex solution to this for such a long time that now it's more about learning something about regex than having the job done! ;) **TNX!**

Comment: @ALFABreezE, some regex tools (like Perl) let you put executable code in the replacement string.  You'd still be doing exactly what @ghostdog74 did here, just in one tightly-packed line of code.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Alan Moore - I don't know what @ghostdog74's script does *(pleeease don't tell him! He's been SO nice... :)*. I don't know shell script. I'm using **Name Mangler** (http://www.manytricks.com/namemangler/) which is based on "AGRegEx" (http://sourceforge.net/projects/agkit/) which claims to be *"a Perl-compatible regular expression framework, based on PCRE Library"*. But I don't know if I can put executable code in the "Replace" field of the Name Mangler's GUI.  Ok.. Now I feel guilty and think I should give @ghostdog script a try, at least. But first I have to find out what "sed" is...

Comment: @ALFA: PCRE emulates the syntax and much of the functionality of Perl's regex matching, but not executable code in replacement strings.  That doesn't necessarily mean *AGKit* doesn't support it, but that capability would have to be provided by AGKit (or maybe AGRegex).  That's how it works in PHP, which also uses PCRE under the hood.

Comment: @Alan Moore - Mmmm... Ok, that's WAY too much for me; I think I'm just gonna trust you. :D  Btw, I just noticed that "Name Mangler" has its own scripting language which can handle (probably) multiple pass of regexes and save them as a single action / droplet (haven't tried, yet). But we're going a little OT. All I wanted to know was if it was possible doing it all with a *single* regex string. And it's not. **Thank You All** for your kindness and patience! :)

Answer (score 1):

To your question "How can I remove the dots in the process of matching?" the answer is "You can't."  The only way to do that is by processing the result of the match in a second step, as others have said.  But I think there's a more basic question that needs to be addressed, which is "What does it mean for a regex to match a given input?"

A regex is usually said to match a string when it describes any *substring* of that string.  If you want to be sure the regex describes the whole string, you need to add the start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors:

```
/^.*x(\d+)\.(.*?)\.[A-Z]{3}.*$/
```

But in your case, you don't need to describe the whole string; if you get rid of the `.*` at either end, it will serve your just as well:

```
/x(\d+)\.(.*?)\.[A-Z]{3}/
```

I recommend you not get in the habit of "padding" regexes with `.*` at beginning and end.  The leading `.*` in particular can change the behavior of the regex in unexpected ways.  For example, it there were two places in the input string where `x(\d+)\.` could match, your "real" match would have started at the second one.  Also, if it's not anchored with `^` or `\A`, a leading `.*` can make the whole regex much less efficient.

I said "usually" above because some tools do automatically "anchor" the match at the beginning (Python's `match()`) or at both ends (Java's `matches()`), but that's pretty rare.  Most of the shells and command-line tools available on *nix systems define a regex match in the traditional way, but it's a good idea to say what tool(s) you're using, just in case.

Finally, a word or two about vocabulary.  The parentheses in `(\d+)` cause the matched characters to be **captured**, not *grouped*.  Many regex flavors also support non-capturing parentheses in the form `(?:\d+)`, which are used for **grouping** only.  Any text that is included in the overall match, whether it's captured or not, is said to have been **consumed** (not *captured*).  The way you used the words "capture" and "group" in your question is guaranteed to cause maximum confusion in anyone who assumes you know what you're talking about. :D

If you haven't read it yet, check out this [excellent tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: Uhu... Sorry if I gave the wrong impression: *I have NO IDEA of what I'm talking about, folks!!* :D As for your answer... It's pretty much exhaustive and, at least, should put an end to my struggles *(thou' I'm pretty sure I'll go on tryin' for a couple of days more :)*. And, yep, I've already taken a glimpse at that "tutorial" (should rather be called a "Bible", actually;) I'll dig into it some more, I promise. As for the `.*` 'padding'  stuff, instead, I need to... ehm... "consume(?)" it, 'cause  if I don't the regex matches, but I can't replace the *whole text* with the result. **TNX!**

Comment: If you want the regex to consume the whole input, it should have anchors at both ends in addition to the `.*` padding.  But I thought you wanted to extract part of it and do some processing on that part.  Did @ghostdog's solution not yield the correct result, even though it wasn't in the form of a single regex replacement?